# initializer_list immutable nature leads to excessive copying

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics, c++14, initializer-list

Why does the access to `std::initializer_list` not allow us to change its content? It's a big disadvantage of `std::initializer_list` when using it for its main purpose (to initialize a container), since it's use leads to excessive copy-construction/copy-assignment, instead of move-construction/move-assignment.

```
#include <initializer_list>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#include <cstdlib>

struct A
{

    A() = default;
    A(A const &) { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl; }
    A(A &&) { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl; }
    A & operator = (A const &) { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl; return *this; }
    A & operator = (A &&) { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl; return *this; }

};

int
main()
{
    std::vector< A >{A{}, A{}, A{}};
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

[Output](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c69676e3d223756d) (as expected):

```
A::A(const A &)
A::A(const A &)
A::A(const A &)
```

Why is its design so constrained?

Comment: As I can infer `{A{}, A{}, A{}}` constructs all content of initializer list in-place.

Comment: Also it is impossible to use `std::initializer_list` to initialize containers of non-copyable objects.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a recent [proposal for movable initializer lists](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4166.pdf), where, in particular, the authors say:

> `std::initializer_list` was designed around 2005 (N1890) to 2007 (N2215), before
>   move semantics matured, around 2009. At the time, it was not anticipated that copy semantics
>   would be insufficient or even suboptimal for common value-like classes. There was a 2008
>   proposal N2801 *Initializer lists and move semantics* but C++0x was already felt to be slipping at that time, and by 2011 the case had gone cold.

Answer (score 4):

good (if unfortunate) answer by Anton.

Here's the source code of the implementation in libc++:

```
template <class _Tp, class _Allocator>
inline _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY
vector<_Tp, _Allocator>::vector(initializer_list<value_type> __il)
{
#if _LIBCPP_DEBUG_LEVEL >= 2
    __get_db()->__insert_c(this);
#endif
    if (__il.size() > 0)
    {
        allocate(__il.size());
        __construct_at_end(__il.begin(), __il.end());
    }
}
```

no move iterators in sight, hence copy construction.

in case it's useful, here's a workaround using a variadic argument list:

```
#include <initializer_list>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <utility>

#include <cstdlib>

struct A
{

    A() noexcept{ std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl; }
    A(A const &) noexcept { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl; }
    A & operator  = (A const &) noexcept { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl; return *this; }
    A(A &&) noexcept { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl; }
    A & operator = (A &&) noexcept { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl; return *this; }

};

template<class T, class...Args>
void append_it(std::vector<T>& v)
{
}

template<class T, class...Args>
void append_it(std::vector<T>& v, T&& t1, Args&&...args)
{
    v.push_back(std::move(t1));
    append_it(v, std::forward<Args&&>(args)...);
}

template<class T, class...Args>
std::vector<T> make_vector(T&& t1, Args&&...args)
{
    std::vector<T> result;
    result.reserve(1 + sizeof...(args));
    result.push_back(std::move(t1));
    append_it(result, std::forward<Args&&>(args)...);
    return result;
}

int
main()
{
    auto v2 = make_vector( A{}, A{}, A{} );

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```