# Why isn't move construction used when initiating a vector from initializer list (via implicit constructor)

Tags: c++, c++14, move-semantics, initializer-list

To demo move semantics, I wrote the following example code, with an implicit constructor from int.

```
struct C {
  int i_=0;
  C() {}
  C(int i) : i_( i ) {}
  C( const C& other) :i_(other.i_) {
    std::cout << "A copy construction was made." << i_<<std::endl;
  }
  C& operator=( const C& other) {
    i_= other.i_ ;
    std::cout << "A copy assign was made."<< i_<<std::endl;
    return *this;
  }
  C( C&& other ) noexcept :i_( std::move(other.i_)) {
    std::cout << "A move construction was made." << i_ << std::endl;
  }
  C& operator=( C&& other ) noexcept {
    i_ = std::move(other.i_);
    std::cout << "A move assign was made." << i_ << std::endl;
    return *this;
  }
};
```

And

```
auto vec2 = std::vector<C>{1,2,3,4,5};
cout << "reversing\n";
std::reverse(vec2.begin(),vec2.end());
```

With output

```
A copy construction was made.1
A copy construction was made.2
A copy construction was made.3
A copy construction was made.4
A copy construction was made.5
reversing
A move construction was made.1
A move assign was made.5
A move assign was made.1
A move construction was made.2
A move assign was made.4
A move assign was made.2
```

Now, the reverse shows the 2 two swaps (each using one move assign and two move constructs), but why are the temporary `C` objects created from the initializer list not possible to move from? I thought I had an initializer list of integers, but I'm now wondering if what I have in between is an initializer list of Cs, which *can't* be moved from (as its const). Is this a correct interpretation? - What's going on?

[Live demo](http://ideone.com/MQqMGd)

Comment: Pretty sure [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8193102/initializer-list-and-move-semantics) is the issue your are experiencing.

Comment: @NathanOliver, that's about moving from an initializer list of C, but I thought I had a list of integers, feeding construction of temporary C objects.

Comment: A vector of type `std::vector<C>` expects an `std::initializer_list<C>` so your list of int's is constructed into a temporary list of C and it is that list of C's that is being copied from.  At least that is what I reason the code to have to do.

Comment: Initializer list construction does copying for non-aggregates. That just the way it is, sorry.

Comment: `std::vector<C>` doesn't have constructor which takes `std::initializer_list<int>` (but it has one for `std::initializer_list<C>`).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [initializer\_list immutable nature leads to excessive copying](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27194519/initializer-list-immutable-nature-leads-to-excessive-copying)

Comment: No orient, that info was already a premise to the question. If you read the answers you'll see the difference.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I thought I had an initializer list of integers, but I'm now wondering if what I have in between is an initializer list of Cs, which can't be moved from (as its const). Is this a correct interpretation?

This is correct. `vector<C>` does not have an `initializer_list<int>` constructor or even an `initializer_list<T>` constructor for some template parameter `T`. What it does have is an `initializer_list<C>` constructor - which is built up from all the ints you pass in. Since the backing of `initializer_list` is a const array, you get a bunch of copies instead of a bunch of moves.

Answer (score 3):

As detailed in my comment you get the copies because a vector of type `std::vector<C>` expects an `std::initializer_list<C>` so your list of `int`'s is constructed into a temporary list of `C`'s and it is that list of `C`'s that is being copied from.

One way you could get around this though is to make a helper function.  Using something like

```
template <typename T, typename Y>
std::vector<T> emplace_list(std::initializer_list<Y> list)
{
    std::vector<T> temp;
    temp.reserve(list.size());
    for (const auto& e: list)
        temp.emplace_back(e);
    return temp;
}

int main()
{
    auto vec2 = emplace_list<C>({1,2,3,4,5});
}
```

You can avoid making copies of the elements from the list because you directly construct them into the vector using `emplace_back`.  If the compiler applies NRVO then you do not even have a move of the vector out of the function.  See this [live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/acacefafd0f47cd2) for g++'s full output.  Do note I have the constructor printing just so you can see it is the only one called.

Answer (score 1):

Thinking a bit more. Here's the self answer:

`std::vector<C>` does not have a constructor of `initializer_list<int>`, or event of T convertible to C. It does have the [constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector)

```
vector( std::initializer_list<T> init,
    const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

So, the `initializer_list` argument list will be an `initializer_list<C>`. Said constructor can do nothing else than copy from the initializer list since they are immutable (used to say const, but the effect here is the same, it can't be move from).

Oh, and that's also what NathanOliver wrote in a comment as I wrote this.

Comment: The only thing that is `const` in the code you posted was the allocator. The real reason copies are made is because list initialization only copies (for non-aggregates, which is what `C` is because you've included user-defined constructors), period.

Comment: @AndyG That's not right. List initialization doesn't only copy (`X x{std::move(y)}` is fine), and `std::initializer_list` is implicitly const.

Comment: @Barry: I meant construction from a `std::initializer_list`, is there an easier way to state that?

Comment: @AndyG Nope. It's a bit confusing because there's list-initialization, there's *initializer-list*, and there's `std::initializer_list`, and they're all different, though related, things. Just gotta be careful.